# Issue on downloading Hadoopizer

Tags: hadoop, bioinformatics

I want to work with the framework hadoopizer but i can't find the hadoopizer.jar , could you please suggest me where i can find it

here is the github site : https://github.com/genouest/hadoopizer/tree/v1.0
They tell me to download hadoopizer from here https://github.com/genouest/hadoopizer/downloads but the hadoopizer bin is not found

Comment: You could clone the source and build it? You're correct that the download link no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

As BinaryNerd above suggested, the link is broken but you can clone the source and build the jar. I was able to do so via the following steps using `git` and `ant`. I knew to use `ant` since it is referenced in the `build.xml` file found in the repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/genouest/hadoopizer.git
cd hadoopizer
```

Here I had to make a change to `build.xml`. I converted the line:

```
<fileset dir="bin"/>
```

to:

```
<fileset dir="src"/>
```

Finally, we run any by calling

```
ant create_run_jar
```

Now, if you look in the newly created `distrib` directory, you'll see `hadoopizer.jar`

Comment: thank you for your help the jar was created , i have another question : so when I'm trying to run the jar they give Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.genouest.hadoopizer.Hadoopizer

Comment: @SalmaHakim avoid asking further questions in the comments, post a new question and reference this post.